# c# asp.net: efficient way to read/write form values to a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to C#.  I'm moving from a non-object-oriented website to an object-oriented one.  What's the best way to read values from an xml file and/or form values?

I've been using a simple function like this:

```
public string theTitle() {return Request.Form["title"];}
```

it works fine until I need to retrieve a bunch of values from the XML files.  It seems like a bad practice to set up an xml connection every time I need to retrieve a value -- I have about 10 values to retrieve like this:

```
public string getTitleFromXML()
{
   // set up xml connection and read a bunch of xml values
   theTitle = theDataRow["title"].ToString();
   return theTitle;
}
```

So what's the best practice here?
thanks!

Gk.

Comment: You should format your code by indenting with four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of retrieving data on each get you should be loading up the object as required, then getting the data. A quick and dirty Example

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Title;
    public string AnotherProperty;

    public void populateFromForm()
    {
       Title = Request.Form["Title"];
       AnotherProperty = Request.Form["AnotherField"];
    } 

    public void populateFromXML()
    {
         // set up xml connection and read a bunch of xml values
         Title = theDataRow["title"].ToString();
         AnotherProperty = theDataRow["AnotherProperty"].ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Then you would use the above like this:

```
MyObject formObject = new MyObject();
MyObject xmlObject = new MyObject();

formObject.populateFromForm();
xmlObject.populateFromXML();

string aTitle = formObject.Title;
sting aAproperty = xmlObject.AnotherProperty;
```

This is a really rough example, you woul be better off using differnt constuctors for each of the scenarios. You would also better off be using private properties with public gettors and settors.

For More info on constructors:

http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/05/c-constructor/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx

For more information on private members and getters and setters

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson10.aspx

Comment: That makes sense.  Perhaps it's out of the scope for this venue, but do you have an example of the different constructors + private properties with public gettors and settors? Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeK, added some links for you

Comment: No Problem George - One tip to the new guy, if you find an answer useful, upvote it using arrows to the left of the answer, and if you really like it accept it by clicking the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Your page has a Title property. Use that.

Comment: 'theTitle' was an example.  Maybe I should have used 'variable1' instead.